# Am I using the right nvidia driver?

Tags: nvidia

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 14.0.4 with Linux kernel 4.2.5 on my HP Envy Slim Notebook which has Nvidia GTX 950M Graphics driver. Everything is working fine but I want to make sure am i using the right graphics driver?
[image: addtional driver screen shot from my ubuntu]

I used the following steps to get it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

And here is the Xorg.0.log

```
    [     3.010] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.1
Release Date: 2015-02-10
[     3.010] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     3.010] Build Operating System: Linux 3.19.0-28-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     3.010] Current Operating System: Linux ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook 4.2.5-040205-generic #201510270124 SMP Tue Oct 27 01:25:49 UTC 2015 x86_64
[     3.010] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.5-040205-generic root=UUID=ed69878c-6802-4708-8aa5-6e41eb8311a6 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[     3.010] Build Date: 11 September 2015  10:33:14AM
[     3.010] xorg-server 2:1.17.1-0ubuntu3.1~trusty1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[     3.010] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[     3.010]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     3.010] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     3.010] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan 23 12:33:45 2016
[     3.012] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     3.016] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     3.016] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     3.016] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     3.016] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     3.016] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     3.016] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     3.016] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     3.016] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     3.019] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     3.019]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     3.019] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     3.019]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     3.019] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     3.019]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     3.020] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     3.020]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     3.020] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     3.020]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     3.020] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[     3.020] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     3.020] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     3.020] (II) Loader magic: 0x5578b8547c60
[     3.020] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     3.020]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     3.020]    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
[     3.020]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[     3.020]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[     3.021] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:191b:103c:8155 rev 6, Mem @ 0x94000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00007000/64
[     3.021] (--) PCI: (0:7:0:0) 10de:139a:103c:8155 rev 162, Mem @ 0x96000000/16777216, 0x80000000/268435456, 0x90000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00005000/128
[     3.024] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[     3.024] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[     3.024] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     3.026] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     3.040] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.040]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.0
[     3.040]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[     3.040] (==) AIGLX enabled
[     3.040] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[     3.040] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[     3.040] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[     3.040] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[     3.040] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     3.040] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[     3.040] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[     3.043] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.043]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.99.917
[     3.043]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     3.043]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[     3.043] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     3.043] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     3.044] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.044]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.17.1
[     3.044]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     3.044]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[     3.044] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     3.044] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     3.046] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.046]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.4
[     3.046]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     3.046]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[     3.046] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     3.046] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     3.047] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.047]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.3
[     3.047]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     3.047]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[     3.047] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[     3.047] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[     3.047] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[     3.047] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[     3.047] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     3.047] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     3.047] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     3.047] (++) using VT number 7

[     3.056] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     3.056] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     3.056] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     3.056] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     3.056] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     3.056] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     3.056] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.056]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.0.2
[     3.056]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[     3.056] (**) FBDEV(1): claimed PCI slot 0@0:2:0
[     3.056] (II) FBDEV(1): using default device
[     3.056] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[     3.056] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     3.056] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[     3.056] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     3.056] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[     3.056] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[     3.056] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     3.056] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     3.056] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: EFI VGA (video memory: 8128kB)
[     3.056] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[     3.056] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[     3.056] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1920x1080 (pitch 1920)
[     3.057] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 207.4 MHz, 85.3 kHz, 77.2 Hz
[     3.057] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0  207.38  1920 1952 2192 2432  1080 1084 1088 1104 -hsync -vsync -csync (85.3 kHz b)
[     3.057] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[     3.057] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     3.057] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     3.057] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     3.058] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.058]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.0
[     3.058]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     3.058] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[     3.058] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[     3.058] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[     3.059] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[     3.059] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.059]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.1.0
[     3.059]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     3.059] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     3.059] (II) Unloading vesa
[     3.059] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[     3.059] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[     3.062] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[     3.062] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[     3.062] (==) RandR enabled
[     3.076] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[     3.076] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[     3.163] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[     3.163] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[     3.175] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[     3.178] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[     3.178] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     3.178] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[     3.178] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[     3.181] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.181]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.9.0
[     3.181]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     3.181]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[     3.181] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[     3.181] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[     3.181] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[     3.181] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[     3.181] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[     3.181] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     3.181] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[     3.181] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[     3.181] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     3.181] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     3.181] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     3.181] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[     3.181] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     3.181] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[     3.181] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[     3.181] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[     3.182] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[     3.182] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[     3.182] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     3.182] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[     3.182] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[     3.182] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     3.182] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     3.182] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     3.182] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[     3.182] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     3.182] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     3.182] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HP Truevision HD (/dev/input/event8)
[     3.182] (**) HP Truevision HD: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     3.182] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HP Truevision HD'
[     3.182] (**) HP Truevision HD: always reports core events
[     3.182] (**) evdev: HP Truevision HD: Device: "/dev/input/event8"
[     3.212] (--) evdev: HP Truevision HD: Vendor 0x5c8 Product 0x379
[     3.212] (--) evdev: HP Truevision HD: Found keys
[     3.212] (II) evdev: HP Truevision HD: Configuring as keyboard
[     3.212] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11:1.0/input/input10/event8"
[     3.212] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP Truevision HD" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[     3.212] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     3.212] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     3.212] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     3.212] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/event4)
[     3.212] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[     3.212] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Receiver'
[     3.212] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: always reports core events
[     3.212] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[     3.268] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc52f
[     3.268] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Found 20 mouse buttons
[     3.268] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Found scroll wheel(s)
[     3.268] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Found relative axes
[     3.268] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Found x and y relative axes
[     3.268] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Configuring as mouse
[     3.268] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Adding scrollwheel support
[     3.268] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[     3.268] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[     3.268] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:046D:C52F.0001/input/input6/event4"
[     3.268] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Receiver" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[     3.268] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: initialized for relative axes.
[     3.268] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     3.268] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[     3.268] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     3.268] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     3.268] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/mouse0)
[     3.268] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     3.268] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     3.269] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/event5)
[     3.269] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     3.269] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Receiver'
[     3.269] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: always reports core events
[     3.269] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[     3.269] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc52f
[     3.269] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Found 1 mouse buttons
[     3.269] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Found scroll wheel(s)
[     3.269] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Found relative axes
[     3.269] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Forcing relative x/y axes to exist.
[     3.269] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Found absolute axes
[     3.269] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[     3.269] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Found keys
[     3.269] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Configuring as mouse
[     3.269] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Configuring as keyboard
[     3.269] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: Adding scrollwheel support
[     3.269] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[     3.269] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[     3.269] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:046D:C52F.0002/input/input7/event5"
[     3.269] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Receiver" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[     3.269] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     3.269] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     3.269] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     3.269] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: initialized for relative axes.
[     3.269] (WW) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: ignoring absolute axes.
[     3.269] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     3.269] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[     3.269] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     3.269] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     3.269] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[     3.269] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     3.269] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     3.269] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event11)
[     3.269] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     3.269] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     3.270] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event12)
[     3.270] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     3.270] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     3.270] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event13)
[     3.270] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     3.270] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     3.270] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event14)
[     3.270] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     3.270] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     3.270] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[     3.270] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     3.270] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[     3.270] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[     3.270] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[     3.270] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[     3.270] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[     3.270] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[     3.270] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3"
[     3.270] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[     3.270] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     3.270] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     3.270] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     3.271] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event7)
[     3.271] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[     3.271] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[     3.271] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[     3.271] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[     3.271] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[     3.271] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.272]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.8.99
[     3.272]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     3.272]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[     3.272] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[     3.272] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[     3.272] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[     3.332] (II) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: found clickpad property
[     3.332] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1362 - 5610 (res 31)
[     3.332] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 1238 - 4700 (res 56)
[     3.332] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
[     3.332] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
[     3.332] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left double triple
[     3.332] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
[     3.332] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[     3.332] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[     3.332] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[     3.396] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5/event7"
[     3.396] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 12)
[     3.396] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[     3.396] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[     3.396] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.036
[     3.396] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     3.396] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[     3.396] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     3.396] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     3.396] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[     3.396] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[     3.396] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[     3.397] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HP Wireless hotkeys (/dev/input/event6)
[     3.397] (**) HP Wireless hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     3.397] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HP Wireless hotkeys'
[     3.397] (**) HP Wireless hotkeys: always reports core events
[     3.397] (**) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[     3.397] (--) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[     3.397] (--) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Found keys
[     3.397] (II) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[     3.397] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input8/event6"
[     3.397] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP Wireless hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[     3.397] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     3.397] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     3.397] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     3.398] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HP WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event15)
[     3.398] (**) HP WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     3.398] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HP WMI hotkeys'
[     3.398] (**) HP WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[     3.398] (**) evdev: HP WMI hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event15"
[     3.398] (--) evdev: HP WMI hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[     3.398] (--) evdev: HP WMI hotkeys: Found keys
[     3.398] (II) evdev: HP WMI hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[     3.398] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input9/event15"
[     3.398] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[     3.398] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     3.398] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     3.398] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     3.400] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[     8.531] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[     8.660] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[     8.669] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[     9.512] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-34CEB476A3CB596DA76FD7010A029F76732EF824.xkm
[    34.198] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer (/dev/input/js0)
[    34.198] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    34.198] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    66.244] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer (/dev/input/event9)
[    66.244] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    66.244] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   566.091] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[   566.091] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[   566.094] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[   600.251] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
```

And this is gpu-manager.log

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
grep dmesg status 256
dmesg status 256 == 0? No
grep dmesg status 256
dmesg status 256 == 0? No
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is fglrx loaded? no
Was fglrx unloaded? no
Is fglrx blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is fglrx kernel module available? no
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:191b
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver. Skipping...
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:139a
BusID "PCI:7@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver. Skipping...
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 0
Has amd? no
Has intel? no
Has nvidia? no
How many cards? 0
Has the system changed? No
main_arch_path x86_64-linux-gnu, other_arch_path i386-linux-gnu
Current alternative: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
Current core alternative: (null)
Is nvidia enabled? no
Is fglrx enabled? no
Is mesa enabled? yes
Is pxpress enabled? no
Is prime enabled? no
Is nvidia available? yes
Is fglrx available? no
Is fglrx-core available? no
Is mesa available? yes
Is pxpress available? no
Is prime available? yes
```

Comment: There's no need to put the whole content of a file of this size here. It pollutes the question and makes it hard to understand. Only do it if someone asks you, and use an external text container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are using the recommended by Ubuntu proprietary Nvidia driver.

And it is the same driver that [Nvidia recommends](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) as the latest stable one.

Other proprietary drivers are erroneously marked as "open source". They are beta **proprietary** ones. You can try them too.

358 is not a beta, but it is not an LTS branch.

Comment: thanks...current one is 361.63 which supports my driver(GTX 950 though mine is 950M). Why gpu-manager.log says something else?

Comment: It does not matter which 9xx you have. These driver support them all. You have a recommended LTS version of the driver.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your system clear from 3rd party drivers Canonical can not check for problematic pieces of code: no. You have a 3rd party version installed and, in that case, should be using the "nouveau".

The 361 open source version is newer than what you are using now. You could attempt installing the 361 and see if that works as well as your current one.

If you would want to keep your system pure or if you would want to use a newer version the answer is no. But if what you ue now works it works. Always a good idea to use a newer version but if those work not as good as what you are using now ... stick with what works.

Comment: 361 didn't worked in my case. So i didn't tried it further.