# How to use only the Nvidia GPU?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a laptop with an integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000 and a dedicated GPU from Nvidia. Since the Intel HD Graphisc is crashing all the time, how can I switch only on the Nvidia GPU and never use the Intel one, not even simultaneously?

Now I have Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 installed. When I boot from windows 7 with all the updates installed I have the same problem and I get this error message: Display driver stopped responding and has recovered.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can refer to this [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/724761/am-i-using-the-right-nvidia-driver). i had a similar problem and fixed it as mentioned in that thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not Intel adapter crashing, but the problem is with the open source Nvidia driver.

Install the correct driver by

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Reboot and switch to Nvidia

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Then log off and on.

But I suspect that Intel will work OK too.

Comment: thank you very much for your time. the problem I think is the Intel Graphics because when I boot on the Windows 7 with all updates to day installed I get this error notification: Display driver stopped responding and has recovered. And I get grey and black screens on Windows 7 too.

Comment: That may really be a hardware problem.

Comment: Do not forget to log off.

Comment: I did + restart. It happens when I open for example multiple tabs on chrome or youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that opening the Additional Drivers app and installing the proprietary NVIDIA driver will automatically make the NVIDIA card be used for everything. Once the installation is done and you have rebooted, you can check by opening the NVIDIA X-server Settings app (not exact name, sorry) and going to the PRIME Profiles section.

Comment: ok, thank you for your time. i did it, i hope it will work

Comment: Good luck. I know that NVIDIA can have issues on Ubuntu.

Comment: I did so, but still have problems, i get grey screens

Comment: when I open for example multiple youtube videos tabs or virtual machine etc