# No proprietary Nvidia drivers, only open source ones

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

After installing Ubuntu, I see that I only have options to install open source Nvidia drivers, not proprietary drivers. In 'Additional Drivers', there are 5 different open source nvidia drivers. Originally it showed 0 drivers, but then I installed something from some PPA and after that it allowed me to choose among the 5 open source drivers.

Does this mean that an Nvidia proprietary driver is not available on my computer? Also, is there an advantage to using open source Nvidia driver vs proprietary?

Comment: I didn't, I will now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Am I using the right nvidia driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/724761/am-i-using-the-right-nvidia-driver)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is actually a misprint from the ppa.

All drivers listed as Nvidia* are proprietary drivers and are not opensource.

Nouveau is the only open source driver available and all others are proprietary.

[Yes, there is an advantage.](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nouveau-end-2015&num=1)

Comment: Oh, I assumed that the open source nvidia drivers were reverse engineered from nvidia or something

Comment: @BotHam Nope, just a misprint. I have added a link (although a bit outdated) that reviews some benchmark comparisons.